# why doesn't solution work and return zero records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Here is my query:

```
select o.order_id, p.sub_category, r.reason 
from  orders o, product p
inner join returns r
on r.order_id=o.order_id
where o.ORDER_DATE ='09/12/2016' ;
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ORA-OO904   "O"."ORDER_ID": invalid identifier
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Could someone help me resolve this issue?

The column does exist in the orders table I don't know why it is giving this error I tried removing the where clause

```
tables 
customers
CUSTOMER_ID    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
CUSTOMER_NAME  VARCHAR2(50) 
SEGMENT_NAME   VARCHAR2(25)

Orders
ORDER_ID              VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
ORDER_DATE            VARCHAR2(30) 
CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL

returns
RETURNED VARCHAR2(26)  
ORDER_ID VARCHAR2(26)  NOT NULL
REASON   VARCHAR2(128)
```

I am trying to create a query that returns a set where the set contains columns from 3 different tables

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix old and new-style joins, only use new, which would also reveal that you are missing a join condition:

```
select o.order_id, p.sub_category, r.reason
from orders o
join product p on p.order_id = o.order_id
join returns r on r.order_id = o.order_id
where o.ORDER_DATE = '09/12/2016';
```

I've guessed that missing condition, as you haven't shown the product table or how they are related.

(You should not storing dates - or numbers - as strings; use the correct data type for the data... [read more](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/see-you-just-cannot-make-this-stuff-up.html).)

With your original query you are trying to join product to returns using `o.order_id`, but the old-style join to orders isn't known to the parser yet, hence the error you get.

Comment: yes, your approach is good of course, but `orders.order_date` column is not of date type Alex.

Comment: Ha, yes... well, that's an even bigger problem *8-)